# Displaying pointer's address in C, without using printf?

Tags: c

I need to recode the printf function using only a handful of functions from the libc library, namely write, malloc and free and a few other basic ones. The only formatting tab that I am having trouble with is %p as I have no idea how to display it using the write function, as passing the address of my pointer to a function that prints strings resulted in empty output. I have also tried typecasting it to a char * and unsigned char * but that did not work either. I have looked online but only found solutions invloving forbidden functions so I am not even sure where to begin.

Comment: How do you normally do it with any other type of data?

Comment: Define "display". Is it output to the console, window, printer or other output device? If you want to store it in a string, use `sprintf`

Comment: `sprintf` and `fwrite` to `stdout`. Something tells me the *real* problem greatly eludes this question, however.

Comment: Sorry I realise my post wasn't very informative so I made an edit. I am not allowed to use sprintf or fwrite. The only function I can use for writing to the standard output is write, and I have tried running the address of the pointer through my putstr function to no avail.

Comment: Try `ptrdiff_t address = the_pointer - NULL;`. That puts the address in an integral field (note: assumes `NULL` is address 0, which is likely but not certain). You can then write code that fills a string with the hexadecimal representation of that number (which is the most common behaviour of `%p`), and then `write()` that string.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

void PrintRecursive(unsigned long long n)
{
 char str[2] = {0};
 char digit = n%16;

 if (n > 0)
  PrintRecursive(n/16);

 if (digit < 10)
  str[0] = '0'+digit;
 else
  str[0] = 'A'+digit-10;

 fwrite(str,1,1,stdout);

}

void PrintPointer(void* p)
{
 if (p)
  PrintRecursive((unsigned long long)p);
 else
  fwrite("0",1,1,stdout);
 fwrite("\n",1,1,stdout);
}

int main()
{
 char      a;
 short     b;
 int       c;

 PrintPointer(&a);
 PrintPointer(&b);
 PrintPointer(&c);
 PrintPointer(NULL);

 return 0;
}

Comment: @barakmanos Would not it be simpler to recursively call  `fwrite("0123456789ABCDEF"+(n&0xF),1,1,stdout); n >>= 4;` until n gets zeroed?

Comment: @Serge: yeah, nice trick!!!

Comment: **Better yet (as suggested in a comment above by @Serge):** #include <stdio.h>

void PrintRecursive(unsigned long long n)
{
 if (n > 0)
  PrintRecursive(n/16);
 fwrite("0123456789ABCDEF"+(n%16),1,1,stdout);
}

void PrintPointer(void* p)
{
 if (p)
  PrintRecursive((unsigned long long)p);
 else
  fwrite("0",1,1,stdout);
 fwrite("\n",1,1,stdout);
}

int main()
{
 char      a;
 short     b;
 int       c;

 PrintPointer(&a);
 PrintPointer(&b);
 PrintPointer(&c);
 PrintPointer(NULL);

 return 0;
}

Comment: mods: It is very clear what the op is asking for, and there are even a few great answers to that problem in the comments. If you don't understand the question refrain from blocking the ones who do understand the question and are trying to help. Closing such questions is not helpful at all.